# PDO column doesn't exist when it does?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have recently uploaded my site to my hosting provider and I am getting a very odd error.

I have imported the exact same database as I was using on my local machine to the web host and it is telling me:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found:
>   1054 Unknown column 'toppers_types.urlPath' in 'field list' in
>   /home/users/xxxxx/html/caketopper.co.uk/public_html/models/GalleryModel.php
>   on line 32

The weird thing is, is that the column does exist and I am 100% I am connecting to the correct database.

Here is the SQL concerned:

```
SELECT toppers.name, toppers.urlName, md.description, toppers_images.thumbSrc,
toppers_types.urlPath
FROM toppers_images, toppers_types, toppers
LEFT JOIN meta_descriptions AS md ON md.topperId = toppers.id
WHERE toppers_images.topperId = toppers.id
AND toppers_types.id = toppers.typeId
AND isPrimary = 1
```

If I take that SQL and put it into phpmyadmin on the webhost, the query runs as expected and I get results.

I am executing the query using PDO:

```
$r = $this->db->prepare($SQL) ;
$r->execute($PDOParams) ;
return $r->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ;
```

Has anyone come across such an anomaly like this before? and if so how do I fix it?

Comment: I hate to even suggest something like this, but… what happens if you quickly try using the `mysql_*` functions to test the same query? If it succeeds, that'd suggest it's an issue with PDO or how it's configured. If it fails, that'd suggest that the issue is with the database connection itself.

Comment: @Matchu It gets rid of the error message but I'm getting no results.

Comment: Can you post the relevant portions of your schema?  I'm assuming you've double-checked the table and column names are correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of the questions of this kind on Stackoverflow and almost all of them ended the same way:
- Oh, I forgot to update the actual database (rename the field, save the proper file etc.)

There is also possible issue with letter case (Unix version is case sensitive while Windows one is not).
Anyway - just test everything.

Run this query using PDO and see the results.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'toppers_types'
```

if field is absent - check server credentials and such
if present - copy-paste it's name to the query

Comment: I put the query into my script and it is not bringing back the column.

Comment: @imperium2335 Like I said in my original question, are you absolutely sure you've got the column name right?  Have you double checked the spelling and capitalization?  Have you looked at the table's schema and checked that the columns it actually has are the same as the columns you think it has? Also, try running these queries through the MySQL shell or a tool like Yog or PHPMyAdmin instead of through your script.